# Update geotiff metadata with rasterio

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

Is there a way to update metadata of an existing geotiff file? I'm particularly interested in setting the `nodata` value. The following does not appear to work

```
import rasterio
from pprint import pprint

path = '/path/to/file.tif'

with rasterio.open(path, 'r+') as src:
    src.meta['nodata'] = -32767
    pprint(src.meta)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The previous answers are misleading or wrong. To modify the nodata value of a GeoTIFF with Rasterio, do this

```
with rasterio.open(tiffname, 'r+') as dataset:
    dataset.nodata = -32767
```

The project has tests of this usage that you may see also: https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/tests/test_update.py#L59-L64. Note that you may have to close and reopen the file (as done in the test) to see the nodata value take effect in your program.

The `meta` property of a dataset is a copy of some of its important metadata. Modifying that object has no effect on the dataset.

Comment: It depends on what really was the question. If it was "Is there a way to update metadata of an existing geotiff file?" like in the question body the gdal_edit answer is not misleading. If one reads only the title that says "with rasterio" and forgets the gdal tag then gdal_edit if off topic and downvote is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify `additional meta data values`  you can use the `dataset.update_tags()` method provided by `rasterio`.

Note: do not confuse `additional` meta data values with the `special` meta data values like `driver`, `dtype`, `nodata`, `width`, `height`, `count`, `crs` or `transform` that are part of `dataset.meta`

Here is an example (derived from the [official documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/tags.html)):

```
import rasterio
file_path = "/path/to/my_file.tif"
meta_data_dict = {"my_variable": 'my_value'}
with rasterio.open(file_path, 'r+') as raster:
    raster.update_tags(**meta_data_dict)
```

`Additional meta data` values are shown in `QGIS`, if you go to the properties of a layer (`right click on layer / properties ...`), select `Information` and check the entries under `More information`

EDIT: In a few cases QGIS did not show the meta data values under `More Information`, although they were accessible with `rasterio`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it right with rasterio but the question includes "gdal" tag so it seems that also GDAL based answers are acceptable. In that case this GDAL tool is made for you http://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html.

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The gdal_edit.py script can be used to edit in place various
>   information of an existing GDAL dataset (projection, geotransform,
>   nodata, metadata).

The script from GDAL trunk can be found at https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_edit.py.