# Change the origin point of the GeoTIFF files using Rasterio

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, affine-transformation

I created a GeoTIFF file in Python (v3.8) using **Rasterio** (v1.2.10). The upper left corner is defined as the GeoTIFF file's origin point, which causes some difficulties in subsequent steps. Is there any way to change the origin point to the lower left corner?

Comment: Convert to TIF with a world file, manually edit the world file?  This link provides some clues to manipulating geotiff metadata with rasterio.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254766/update-geotiff-metadata-with-rasterio

Comment: One way is to set the pixel size Y from negative to positive. Then the next rows after the first one are placed above it, not below. This will flip the image by the same but maybe it is what you want.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? The image origin is usually the top left while the geographic origin is usually the lower left.

Comment: @lan Turton, I use the GeoTIFF data as input for a model (Model of Emissions of Gases and Aerosols from Nature (MEGAN)). The lower left corner is defined as the origin point in the model.